# Vertical smooth scrolling of values in a text view

Tags: android, scroll, vertical-scrolling

I have a text view where in i have to keep ages between 1-99. I also have two buttons ^ and v(i mean up and down arrows) on clicking them the values of the age should smoothly scroll to next or previous value.

I have been trying different ways but couldnt achieve smooth scrolling. Can anyone please give me any idea of how to achieve the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the animation framework.

When pressing down, start the 'down'-animation. 
When pressing up, start the 'up'-animation.

Read more about animation here: http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=343

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to simply put the TextView within a ScrollView, and let the arrows interact with the ScrollView, by using things like the fling method and playing around with the velocity parameter to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

View animation is not much matured and hence i am noy sure if that can be used for moving the views.

Please find the description below:

> Another disadvantage of the view
>   animation system is that it only
>   modified where the View was drawn, and
>   not the actual View itself. For
>   instance, if you animated a button to
>   move across the screen, the button
>   draws correctly, but the actual
>   location where you can click the
>   button does not change, so you have to
>   implement your own logic to handle
>   this.

[Source](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/animation.html)

To scroll smoothly you can try using the scroller component.

[Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Scroller.html)

What you would need to do is pass the duration of the scroll in the constructor and then use the property

> setFinalY(int newY)
>    to increment the counter position by 1 unit (equal to the height of the item).

Please let me know if that helps!